# Как конвертировать строку во время?

Tags: c

Как конвертировать строку вида DD/MM/YYYY в дату, чтобы вернуло -1 в случае неудачи?
Или как проверить, является ли строка вида DD/MM/YYYY существующей датой?

Comment: Никак. Недостаточно данных. Например, что значит *существующая дата*? 2038 год — это существующая дата?

Answer (score 1):

> Как конвертировать строку вида DD/MM/YYYY в дату

Для этого существуют две функции:

1. Функция  *strptime()*  является  конвертирующей функцией, дополняющей *strftime*(3): она преобразует символьную строку, на которую указывает s, сохраняя значения в структуре tm (описывает  время  в виде компонент, broken-down time) согласно формата, заданного в format.

Если  *strptime()*  не  может  найти  все  соответствия  строке  формата,  то  возникает  ошибка и возвращается значение NULL.

2. Функция  *getdate()*  преобразует  строковое  представление  даты  и времени из буфера, на который указывает *string* в разделённое на компоненты время. Разделённое время сохраняется в структуре *tm* и  указатель  на  неё  возвращается  в качестве результата. Структура *tm* находится в статической области и, таким образом, будет перезаписана при следующих вызовах *getdate()*.

При успешном выполнении  *getdate()*  возвращает  указатель  на  *struct  tm*.  В  противном  случае возвращается  NULL